# Show $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{c{a^{bn}}}{n!} = 0$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{c{a^{bn}}}{n!} = 0$ for all $a,c$ belonging to ${R}$ and b belonging to $Z$.

For $b=0$, the expression is reduced to
$\frac{c}{n!}$ and is easy to solve.

For $b<0$ , it is reduced to
$\frac{c}{n!{a^{|bn|}}}$ and the limit is easy to solve.

For $b>0$ ,I  am a little confused but l want to see if l can use squeeze rule.

$$\frac{-|ca^{bn}|}{n^n} < \frac{ca^{bn}}{n!}< \frac{|ca^{bn}|}{n^n}$$

Any other any problems with the inequality and can l solve it in an easier way.

Comment: Show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}<1$ where $u_n=\frac{ca^{bn}}{n!}$

Comment: @Tuvasbein, the test shows that the sequence converges but l also need to show that it converges to zero.

Comment: There must be a typo.  There's no occurrence of $x$ in the argument of the limit.  Do you mean to take the limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}<1$ then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}u_n=0$.

Comment: @Robert Shore Yes, silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ca^{bn}}{n!}= c \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(a^b)^n}{n!}.$$

For $n \gt 2a^b =m$ (this is intended as a definition for $m$), this fraction is less than a constant times $\frac{1}{2^{n-m}}$, which obviously goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (since $m$ is a constant).

Answer (score 0):

We can use Sturling's formula:
$n!\sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$
$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{ca^{bn}}{ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{c(a^be)^n}{n^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}=0$

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider $e^x=\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n} {n!}$

Especially, we can put $c=1$ wlog as if we can show our result here the assumption would be true for all $c$.

If we consider the series $\sum u_n$ with $u_n=\frac {a^{bn}} {n!} $ the series converges if the term $u_n$ has limit  $0$. But it converges to $e^{a^b} $ by Taylor series.